# Why google did not have an appengine mapreduce output writer for datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce

Google Developer webpage (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/readers_writers) list a number of Output writers for File output and Blobstore output. But it did not have Output writer for Datastore.

Any reason why this is so?  Could it be performance issue or technical issue or others?

Answer (score 1):

No. It is possible. In fact this is done in Java:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/dataprocessing/mapreduce_classes#the_output_class

It is easy to add it yourself if you feel it is important:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/readers_writers#RecordsReader
The code is hosted here:
https://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/

Answer (score 0):

it isn't needed... you can `yield operations.db.Put(entity)` directly from the reduce callback and your entities will go into the mutation pool to be flushed at the end